# springboot exceptionhandling without controller class

Tags: spring-boot, exception

How to handle exception handling in Spring Boot 1.5.4 without controller class?  Currently, I have only entity & repository class as below.

Task.class: (entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Length(min = 1)
    private String name;

    public Task() {

    }

    public Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Task(Long id, String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

Repository.class:

```
public interface TaskRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Task, Long> {
}
```

POST method:  return 200 ok

http://localhost:8080/tasks

```
{
"name" : "test"
}
```

But,

```
{
"name" : ""
}
```

returns 500 , instead of 400 error.

Pls let me know, if any way to handle this exception without a controller class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a global [@ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) with the [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotation. Basically, you define which Exception to handle with @ExceptionHandler within the class with @ControllerAdvice annotation, and then you implement what you want to do when that exception is thrown.

Like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = RepositoryRestExceptionHandler.class)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ValidationException.class, JsonParseException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> yourExceptionHandler(Exception e) {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
        response.put("message", "Bad Request");
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

See also: http://www.ekiras.com/2016/02/how-to-do-exception-handling-in-springboot-rest-application.html

Comment: I do not have any controller class in my app.  So, @ControllerAdvice annotation will work ?

Comment: Thanks... i have added exception classes and now able to see 404 error.  But, how to get correct error code as 400 for my below request ?

Scenario:  empty string, string without quotes, empty body

`{
"name" : ""
}`

`{
"name" : test
}`

`{

}`

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error here and I saw that the exception was a ConstraintViolationException, which is a ValidationException... So I updated my answer to ValidationException... Check it out

Comment: And for the "{}" case, you need to add `@NotBlank` on *name* (Task class)